# Difference between a QNX "Flash filesystem image" and an "OS image"?

Tags: filesystems, qnx, qnx-neutrino, qnx-ifs

What is the difference between a QNX "Flash filesystem image" and a "OS image"?

I've got an old PC104(x86) unit that works solely with a CompactFlash card drive and now I'm wondering if I need the first or the second one to put on my CF card. The QNX docs [[1](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.building%2Ftopic%2Fbuilding_nto_IMAGES.html&cp=1_0_1_2_0)] states that only the OS image is bootable. I need the CF card to be bootable since there's no other drive to boot from. Thus, does that mean I can't benefit from the Flash file system image approach with my current setup?

I don't want to use the System Builder to customize my QNX OS or anything, since I still need the QNX SDP to run on the target.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I dealt with this, but the term "Flash filesystem image" is the bigger of the two.  The filesystem image is the collection of bytes required to represent the filesystem on the flash device.  It may hold such things as the OS image, your /tmp directory, your /home directory, and so on.  The OS image, on the other hand, holds a second stage boot loader, the OS itself, and possibly some drivers.

Comment: Thx for you answer. So the idea is to create a small bootable OS image (aka boot partition) first and then link it to the actual "flash filesystem image"?